# Creating a view in SQL with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I wanted to make a view with all records from the 3 tables I have.. But I'm getting an error and I don't know how to solve it.

The error is that Customer.customerID is duplicated.

```
Create view overview as
Select
customer.customerID,
customer.username, 
customer.name, 
customer.surname, 
customer.city, 
customer.street, 
customer.zipcode, 
customer.birthdate, 
customer.`payment method`,
customer.screenname,
order.OrderID,
order.customerID,
order.date,
order.GameID,
games.GameID,
games.game,
games.price,
games.released,
games.genre,
games.grid
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order
ON customer.customerID = order.customerID
INNER JOIN games
ON games.GameID = order.GameID
```

The tables and their rows:

order
OrderID, customerID, date, GameID

games
GameID, game, price, released, genre, grid

customer
customerID, username, name, surname, city, street, zipcode, birthdate, payment method, screenname

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the double named rows like @Mahmoud_Gamal suggested but it gave me an issue with SQL making a record with every combination possible from the data in other records like:

Customer 1 | Order1 | Game1

Customer 2 | Order1 | Game1

Customer 1 | Order2 | Game2

I solved it by using "select distinct", never though it would give soo much pain by forgetting to use the distinct function...

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomerID` column is selected twice with the same name, you have to give one of them a different name using alias `AS ...` like this:

```
Create view overview as
Select
customer.customerID,
customer.username, 
customer.name, 
customer.surname, 
customer.city, 
customer.street, 
customer.zipcode, 
customer.birthdate, 
customer.`payment method`,
customer.screenname,
order.OrderID,
order.customerID AS OrderCustomerId, -- this
order.date,
order.GameID,
games.GameID gamesGameID,           -- This too
games.game,
games.price,
games.released,
games.genre,
games.grid
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order
ON customer.customerID = order.customerID
INNER JOIN games  ON games.GameID = order.GameID
```

Or remove it from the select as it is the same value as the `Customers.CustomerId`.

Comment: Doesn't that give me the same info twice?

Comment: @BadAtPHP - Yes, thats why I said, you can get rid of them since its the same column.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me the same issue what I would've gotten with @Gordon his solution.

I had to use select distinct, which solved the issue I was having. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You have two columns in your result set that are named the same, `CustomerId`. Try this:

```
Create view overview as
Select
customer.customerID as CustomerId1,
customer.username, 
customer.name, 
customer.surname, 
customer.city, 
customer.street, 
customer.zipcode, 
customer.birthdate, 
customer.`payment method`,
customer.screenname,
order.OrderID,
order.customerID as CustomerId2,
order.date,
order.GameID,
games.GameID,
games.game,
games.price,
games.released,
games.genre,
games.grid
FROM customer
INNER JOIN order
ON customer.customerID = order.customerID
INNER JOIN games
ON games.GameID = order.GameID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate columns in the `select`.  In addition to `CustomerId`, you also have `GameId`.  Just list each column once:

```
Select
    customer.customerID,
    customer.username, 
    customer.name, 
    customer.surname, 
    customer.city, 
    customer.street, 
    customer.zipcode, 
    customer.birthdate, 
    customer.`payment method`,
    customer.screenname,
    `order`.OrderID,
    `order`.date,
    `order`.GameID,
    games.game,
    games.price,
    games.released,
    games.genre,
    games.grid
```

The duplicates are unnecessary because the `join` conditions would just make them the same anyway.

As a note;  `order` is a very bad name for a table because it is a reserved word.  You should avoid using reserved words for table and column names.  These then need to be escaped in queries, which just clutters the queries.

By the way, for this type of query, if you want all the columns from the three tables without duplicates, you can use `*` with the `using` clause:

Create view overview as
    Select *
    FROM customer INNER JOIN
         `order`
         USING (CustomerId) INNER JOIN
         games
         USING (GameID)

Comment: I tried that, but then I get about 15 colums where the query creates every possible combination of the records. Also order isn't the actual name of the table, I translated it to order since the original database is dutch

Comment: @BadAtPHP . . . Changing the `select` clause should not cause "every possible combination of the records".  The `using` clause should be exactly equivalent to what you are doing now, except you can use `select *` and not have to worry about column duplicates.